# Database: Repositories with NoSQL/Document Database (DDD)

Tags: database, orm, nosql, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

Looking for any advice from anyone who has migrated their repositories from relational DB to a NoSQL?

We are currently building an App using a Postgres database & ORM (SQLAlchemy). However, there is a possibility that at a later date we may need to migrate the App to an environment that currently only supports a couple of NoSQL solutions.

With that in mind, we're following the Persistence-Orietated approach to repositories covered in Vaughn Vernon's Implementing Domain-Driven Design. This results in the following API:

```
save(aggregate)
save_all(aggregates)
remove(aggregate)
get_by_...
```

Without going into detail, the ORM specific code has been hidden away in the repository itself. The Session is only used for the short span of time when data is retrieved, or updated, and then immediately committed and closed (in the repos methods). This means lots of merging on save, and not the most efficient use of the Session.

```
def save(aggregate):
try:
session.merge(aggregate)
commit
except:
rollback

def get():
try:
aggregate = session.query_by(id)
session.expunge
commit
except:
rollback
return aggregate
```

etc etc

The advantages:

- We are limiting ourselves to updating a single Aggregate per Use Case, so the lack of fully utilising the UOW Transaction Control in the Application Service is minimal (outside of performance). Transaction Control is enabled in the repos while the aggregate is written to ensure the full aggregate is persisted.
- No ORM specific code leaks outside of the Repositories, which would need to be re-coded in the advent of switching to a NoSQL db anyway.

So if we do have to switch to a NoSQL DB, we should have a minimal amount of work to do.

However, almost everything I have read encourages Transactional Behaviour to live in the Application Service Layer. Although I believe there is a distinction here between Business Transactional and DB Transactional.

Likewise, we're taking performance hit, in that we are asking the session factory for a session on every call to the repository. Most services contain about 3 or so calls to a repository.

So, the question to anyone who has migrated from Relational to a NoSQL DB?

- Does the concept of a Unit of Work / Session mean anything in a NoSQL world?
- Should we fully embrace the ORM in the meantime, and move the UOW/Session outside of the Repository into the Application Service?
- If we do that, what was the level of effort to re-engineer the Application Service, if we need to migrate to a NoSQL solution in the end. (The repositories will need to be re-written in any instance).
- Finally, anyone had much experience writing a implementation agnostic repository?

PS. Understand we could drop the ORM entirely and go pure SQL in the meantime, but we have beed asked to ensure we are using an ORM.

Comment: Yes, but the current database is a Relational Database. The question relates to coding the current App in a way that will make a future switch to a non-relational DB as painless as possible (as it's been indicated to us we may need to do this and it is outside of our control.).

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: In this answer I focus on document db's based on the questions title. Of course other NoSQL stores exist with vastly different characteristics (for example graph db's, using event sourcing and others).

---

It should not be a problem really.

In document db's your entire aggregate should be a single document. This way you have exactly the same guarantees that you need for transactional consistency. Regardless of how many entities change within the aggregate, you're still storing a document. You will need to make sure you enforce some form of optimistic concurrency (through an etag or version or similar), and not a Unit of Work pattern, but after that your transactional requirements are covered.

I can't really comment whether you fully embrase a UoW pattern now, vs rely on ORM implementation etc. This really depends a lot on your current situation and details about implementation. What I can say though is that it is quite probable that you won't need to migrate from normal form (SQL) to documents all in one go. Start from a simple one so that you can see what works for you and what doesn't.

I don't know if implementation-agnostic repositories exist, but that doesn't make a lot of sense to me. The whole point of a repository is encapsulating persistence, so you can't abstract it: there won't be any other responsibility allocated to them. Also, you can't assume that the repository will need to compose different models into the aggregate model: this is specific to platform, so it's not agnostic.

Another final comment: I see in your question that for documents you wrote `save_all(aggregates)`. I'm not sure what you're referring to, but at minimum, each aggregate save should be wrapped in its own transaction, otherwise this operation violates transactional boundary characteristic of Aggregate.

Comment: Thank you Skleanthous. Great response. We're already using optimistic concurrency and a version, so that is good to hear.

Comment: In terms of the implementation-agnostic repository. I could have been clearer. It's more a case of the ORM leaking into the Application layer via the Session/UOW. It sounds like by working with the data in a disconnected state, and hiding the Session/UOW in the repo, we're mimicking what we'll do with a NoSQL DB and optimistic concurrency. The save_all method follows Vernon's book. It's mostly convenience to add a collection of aggregate roots (of the same type) to the repository.

Comment: @SKleanthous not all NoSQL databases are document dbs, although they do go along well with DDD aggregates.

Comment: @guillaume31 You are right of course, and I am aware, but the question was posed asking about document db in the title. Due to that I focused my answer exclusively on that. For example personally I have a preference on event sourcing to model my domain. Other solutions still, may have other benefits (for example in-mem databases with streaming capabilities).

Answer (score 0):

> Does the concept of a Unit of Work / Session mean anything in a NoSQL
>   world?

Yes, it can still be an interesting concept to have. Just because you're using a NoSQL storage doesn't mean that the need for some sort of business transaction management disappears. Many NoSQL databases have drivers or third party libraries that manage change tracking. See [RavenDB](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/client-api/session/what-is-a-session-and-how-does-it-work) for instance.

Sure, if you're only ever loading one aggregate per transaction and if your NoSQL unit of storage matches an aggregate perfectly, most of a Unit of Work's features will be less important, but you'll still be facing exceptions to that rule. Besides, the part of a UoW that's relevant in any case is Commit and possibly Abort.

> Should we fully embrace the ORM in the meantime, and move the
>   UOW/Session outside of the Repository into the Application Service?

What I recommend instead is materializing the concept of Unit of Work in a full fledged class:

```cs
class UnitOfWork {
  void Commit() 
  {
    // Call your ORM persistence here
  }
}
```

Application Services are just the place where the Unit of Work is called, not where it is implemented.

> If we do that, what was the level of effort to re-engineer the
>   Application Service, if we need to migrate to a NoSQL solution in the
>   end. (The repositories will need to be re-written in any instance).

It depends on a lot of other parameters such as Unit of Work support by your NoSQL API or third party libraries, and similarity in shape between Aggregates and the NoSQL storage. It can range from practically no work to writing a full UoW/change tracking implementation yourself. If the latter, extracting UoW logic from the Repository to a separate class won't be the hardest part of the job.

> Finally, anyone had much experience writing a implementation agnostic
>   repository?

I concur with SKleanthous here - implementation agnostic repos don't make much sense IMO. You've got your repository *abstractions* (interfaces) which are of course agnostic but when it comes to implementations, you have to address a particular persistent storage.